# Can I approximate the CO concentration of a combustion product, if I know the CO2 and O2 concentration?

Tags: stoichiometry, gas-laws, combustion, hydrocarbons, fuel

Assume I have the product (exhaust gas) from a combusted air/petrol mix. The mixing ratio was richer than stoichiometric (i.e., air:fuel < 14.67 in this case), so there was no excess of oxygen.

I know the $\ce{CO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ concentration of the combustion product, say 11% and 2% respectively. I also know that the combustion product only consists of $\ce{CO2}$, $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{CO}$ and leftover $\ce{O2}$. (All fuel combusts to $\ce{H2O}$ and either $\ce{CO2}$ or $\ce{CO}$.)

Is it possible to approximate the $\ce{CO}$ concentration of the combustion product with that information?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work since there are too many unknowns. Combustion is a very complex process. In most chemistry problems "complete" combustion is typically assumed.

Comment: You’re ignoring uncombusted and partially combusted hydrocarbons in the equation.

Comment: If you knew the H2O concentration you could estimate CO from an oxygen balance.  If you knew the uncombusted fuel concentration you could estimate CO from a carbon balance.

Comment: @MaxW What unknowns would have to be known then? I know that real combustions are more complex, but i'm looking for an approximation, so the calculation can be kept simple.

Comment: @Jan I know, I said that in my question; that the combustion only results in CO2, H2O and CO. I assume al HC to be combusted to either CO or CO2 to keep things simple.

Comment: @CurtF. If I don't know the H2O concentration, and I assume no uncombusted HC. Is an oxygen balance also calculable with that? If you know the CO2 concentration that would be achieved by a completely burned stoich mixture,(around 16% i believe) would that make an oxygen balance calculable?

Comment: I guess if you are willing to assume that all fuel carbon that was not converted to CO2 was converted to CO, you could estimate CO.

Comment: @CurtF. I can assume that, because in reality, only a very small part of HC will remain. If I ignore that, it won't be of significant influence on my outcome; the accuracy of my sensors is of way more influence. Could you help me approximate the CO?